# Loop Processing With Session Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, session

I have an issue with an asp application with c# backend and am seeking some guidance.

I have a webform that takes two numbers, a starting and end number, and splits it into blocks of 20, assigns the starting number and ending number to a session variable for each block, then passing the session variable to an asp page for further processing, one block of 20 (or less) at a time.

It seems the loop iterates until the last time and then pushes the commands out, which by that time my Session variable has been overwritten to 'the last batch'.

The intended operation would be for a batch of 73 (example), there would be 4 windows opened, with 1-20 with the first session call, 21-40 with the second session call, 41-60 with the third session call, and 61-73 for the last session call, opening a new browser window with each of the batches on every loop thru.  Right now, I get 4 windows, but only the last 61-73 batch in each window.

I do believe this is normal loop behavior, but is there anyway around it?

code example:

```
int[] serialArray = Enumerable.Range((Convert.ToInt32(startNum.Text)), 1 + 
(Convert.ToInt32(endNum.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(startNum.Text))).ToArray();              

bool keepGoing = true;

int index = 0; //starting array number
int endArray = serialArray.Length; //modifying array limit
int yyy = 19; //end array number                             


while (keepGoing) 
{                    
    int[] smallArray = serialArray.Skip(index).Take(20).ToArray();

    if (endArray <= 20) 
    {                        
        reportPopper(serialArray[index], serialArray.Last());
    }
    else 
    {            
        reportPopper(serialArray[index], serialArray[yyy]);
    }                   

    if (smallArray.Count() >= endArray)
    {
        keepGoing = false;
    }

    endArray -= smallArray.Count();
    index += smallArray.Count();
}
```

then:

```
protected void reportPopper(int a, int b)
{            
    int startNumber = a;
    int endNumber = b;

    Session["SerialStart"] = startNumber; //batch index start
    Session["SerialEnd"] = endNumber; //batch index end 

    string redirect = "<script>window.open('PrintBatchReport.aspx');</script>";
    Response.Write(redirect);
}
```

Comment: This isn't how the page life cycle works. You are essentially queuing up 4 `window.open` calls without telling them what to process. You will need to generate unique session variables for each redirect and pass them to the `window.open` so they process the correct batches.

Comment: Why not pass `SerialStart` and `SerialEnd` in the querystring? Then each window could have its own range, because each window has its own URL.

Comment: I suggest giving them link to open all the four windows as in [How to open two popup window on a button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535048/how-to-open-two-popup-window-on-a-button-click)

Comment: Great suggestions to everyone.  I thought the issue was either a timing problem, or @mjw mentioning unique session variables for each redirect.  I'm not 100% sure on how to modify a session variable to make it unique each time quite yet, so sending the start/end in the url might do the trick here like John Wu suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First suggestion (unique session variables) combined with second suggestion (query string) will give you the range for each URL plus unique session variables if you need them for something beyond the popups:

```
protected void reportPopper(int a, int b)
{                
    Session["SerialStart_" + a.ToString()] = a; //batch index start
    Session["SerialEnd_" + b.ToString()] = b; //batch index end 

    string redirect = String.Format("<script>window.open('PrintBatchReport.aspx?start={0}&end={1}');</script>", a, b);
    Response.Write(redirect);
}
```

Now, in `PrintBatchReport.aspx`:

```
int start = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["start"].ToString());
int end = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["end"].ToString());
var startSession = Session["SerialStart_" + start.ToString()];
var endSession = Session["SerialEnd_" + end.ToString()];
//DO STUFF
```

If you don't need the Session variables for anything except the range boundaries, you can kill everything session related and you should be in good shape.

Comment: That's magical.  I was able to get the redirect to work pretty well, but for some reason I was only getting 1 window to open even tho the code behind was processing and sending multiple unique url's with correct params, but this code of yours works perfectly.  Thank you for your help.